# Heroku Laravel 500 (Internal Server Error) oauth-public.key does not exist

Tags: laravel, api, rest, vue.js, heroku

[OAUTH Public Key is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My7fb.png)

[oauth-public.key is exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsA3h.png)

I uploaded a question board using Laravel, Vue, RESTful API on Heroku.
When I log in and add a question, I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) called
`"Key path \"file:///app/storage/oauth-public.key\" does not exist or is not readable"`.

Github: https://github.com/2020software/Sample-Vuedev

Heroku Question board: https://samplevueqa.herokuapp.com/

Login id : text@example.com
Login pw: password

Thank you for those who have solved the same problem!

Comment: did you run php artisan passport:install

Comment: Yes, I did. As you can see in the image of "OAUTH Public Key is Here", the key is in the Storage folder, so I think there is a problem with the path. Please tell me about the path setting.

Comment: Do I have to "run php artisan passport:install" again after deploying locally to Heroku?

Comment: yes because in the image these files are being ignored

Comment: "Encryption keys already exist. Use the --force option to overwrite them." Can i run " php artisan passport:install  --force"?

Comment: I runned "heroku ps:exec -a your_app_name" next "php artisan passport:keys" I solved!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Verify that the file in fact doesn't exist, rather than just having incorrect permissions
2. Verify that it also doesn't exist in app/storage/app. I've had it happen where Passport's default location for creating new keys didn't quite match where the Auth middleware was looking. You can fix this in config/filesystems.php if need be.
3. Make sure to run [`php artisan passport:keys`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#deploying-passport)

Comment: php artisan passport:keys
"Encryption keys already exist. Use the --force option to overwrite them." Should I force?

Comment: There is a oauth-public.key  to "sample-vueqa / storage" should I fix it with config /filesystems.php? How do I enter the code?

Comment: Your default filesystem config may be pointing to a different root storage directory than wherever the middleware is expecting to find your keys. So either move the keys to the expected folder (which you'd have to remember to do in Production as well), or change the 'root' value.

Comment: `'root' => storage_path('app/public'),` I put public.key in "strage//app/public", but I still get an same error. How to set in Production?

Comment: storage / oauth-public.key What happens to ` filesystems.php 'disks' => 'public' => 'root' => strage_path('????') ` in this case?  I also pasted the screenshot into the question.

Comment: I runned "heroku ps:exec -a your_app_name" next "php artisan passport:keys" I solved!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I runned `heroku ps:exec -a your_app_name` next run `php artisan passport:keys` I solved!!